# Was ist ein „deutscher Stuhlkreis“?

Tags: etymology, idiom

In diesem [Artikel](http://www.zeit.de/2016/03/sexismus-fluechtlinge-islamismus-araber-frauen/seite-2) wird ein *deutscher Stuhlkreis* erwähnt.

> Deutschland hat nach zwei militärisch und moralisch verlorenen Kriegen, nach Jahren des antiautoritären und antipatriarchalen Kampfes eine immense Fertigkeit darin entwickelt, Männlichkeit zu entgiften. Nicht wahr, liebe Geschlechtsgenossen, wir haben es doch selbst erlebt, am eigenen Leibe: **Dem deutschen Stuhlkreis entkommt auf Dauer keiner**.

Nach einer Google-Suche bin ich immer noch nicht schlauer.

Was bedeutet das bzw. auf was will der Autor anspielen?
Was für eine (geschichtliche?) Begebenheit steckt dahinter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wir haben es mit keinem besonderen Idiom zu tun, sondern lediglich mit einem Stuhlkreis, der von deutschen Staatsbürgern gebildet wird – also ein deutscher Stuhlkreis ist. (Großschreibung von *deutsch* wäre hier verkehrt, denn der Stuhlkreis gewinnt durch das Adjektiv keine tiefergehende Bedeutung, ganz im Gegensatz zum *Schwarzen Brett* oder zum *Roten Kreuz*.)

Allerdings stecken einige Stereotype in dem Satz. Zunächst einmal dass überhaupt ein Stuhlkreis gebildet wird. Man könnte sich zum diskutieren auch schlicht am Marktplatz treffen, Rudel bilden und quer durcheinander schreien, oder man könnte die Auseinandersetzung auch gleich mit Fäusten austragen. Über Deutsche heißt es, dass sie zwar gerne und ausgiebig diskutieren, dass aber gleichzeitig ein geordneter Rahmen für diese Diskussion gewählt wird – eben der Stuhlkreis, am besten noch mit Vorstellungsrunde, Redeliste. Dieser soll – weitere Stereotype – Emotionen abkühlen und Argumente hervortreten lassen. Man denke nur an das Schlagwort der »politischen Lösung« (während die andere Seite schon mit ihrer Armee einmarschiert ist). Diese Stereotype versucht der Autor mit dem Adjektiv *deutsch* beim Leser hervorzurufen.

Es ist außerdem ein Rattenschwanz an Geschlechtsstereotypen enthalten, zum Beispiel dass Frauen lieber diskutieren und die männlich-brutale Aggresivität durch eine Diskussionsrunde abgekühlt werden muss, dass außerdem dieses Spiel in Deutschland so ausgiebig gespielt worden ist, dass der ehemals »starke«, »männliche« Mann »verweichlicht« oder gar »verweiblicht« worden ist und einiges mehr.

**Auf keinen Fall spielt *deutscher Stuhlkreis* auf irgendein geschichtliches oder sonstwie relevantes Ereignis an.** Es kann nur über die Summe der Assoziationen verstanden werden.

Comment: Ich würde noch hinzufügen, dass ich "Stuhlkreis" zuerst einmal mit Kindergarten in Verbindung bringen würde. Aber vielleicht geht das nur mir so...

Comment: @Gerhard Schon, aber die Anonymen Alkoholiker sind eine zweite, starke Assoziation bei mir ;)

Answer (score 7):

tl,dr: Stuhlkreis ist hier schlicht ein Symbol für eine gleichberechtigte Diskussionsrunde

Was ein Stuhlkreis ist, ist dir klar? Eine Diskussionform, in dem eine Gruppe von Personen in einem Kreis sitzt (mit dem Ziel, dass niemand eine exponierte Stellung hat und sich alle ansehen können). Wichtige Konnotation ist Pädagogik, vor allem in unteren Jahrgängen und damit mittelbar auch (zumindest für den Impetus des Texts) als "weiblich" empfundene Kommunikation.

Die Unterstellung des Textes ist nun, dass dieser Stuhlkreis für die Problemlösung/Debattenkultur in Deutschland/mit Deutschland symbolisch ist. Während in $LAND jemand (vorgeblich der Vorsitzende, Anführer, ...) entscheidet und diese Entscheidung dann den Frauen, Kindern, Alten kund tut, gibt es in Deutschland Planfeststellungsverfahren, Bürgeranhörungen und -begehren, Arbeitskreise, Elternabende und andere Institutionen oder Maßnahmen die Teilhabe sicherstellen.

Comment: "mit dem Ziel, dass niemand eine exponierte Stellung hat und sich alle ansehen können" - das zweite Ziel klingt ja sehr plausibel, aber am ersten Ziel habe ich starke Zweifel. In praktisch allen Stuhlkreisen, die mir bislang begegnet sind, gab es eine Art Moderator/Gesprächsleiter.